# How should you market Android Apps (Free vs Paid)

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, google-play, xamarin

so I want to have a paid and a free version of a android app... I'm here to ask you if it would be better to:

(A).  Make 2 separate apps, 1 free, 1 paid and post them both on Google play?

(B). Post the free app on Google play with limitations, and have the user upgrade to the full version by buying the full version IN app?

(C). Create a license verification that users will need to purchase from Google Play?

What do you guys think would be the better option? or what is you're suggestion?

I'm using Xamarin for Android if it matters...

Thanks!

Comment: Nice question, but not a programming question. Ask on chat maybe : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a [Freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) App (Option B) because of these reasons:

- Users can test your app without paying money
- The user can upgrade the app without leaving the app
- Only one app has to get high rankings in the store
- Free apps are downloaded more often
- After the purchase the user won't have two versions on the device (as in Option A)
- You only have to submit one version to Google Play (and you also have only one version in your development tools)
- Other apps that use this business-model do extremely well

Comment: Yeah I agree that this is the best option. But users are a-holes and they will give bad reviews complaining that the app is not free as it states.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, A is the best option (creating two apps, one is paid and one is free). It is a common practice, that the free one has ads in it. If anyone downloads the free version and he really likes your app (or just wants to get rid of ads), he will probably buy the paid one.